# Lubuntu 13 is Unstable; Trouble DLing Alternate Version

Tags: lubuntu

I want to download and install 32-bit Lubuntu 14.

However, lots of things are interfering with that.

Also, the fact that I'm temporarily homeless right now is making a download even more difficult.

A major problem is that it's estimated to take about 5 hours to DL the desktop image. Downloading for that length of time can surpass my library wifi session, which breaks the connection and prompts me to re-log-in. The ends the download and makes me need to start over.

Secondly, there's also the risk that my monitor will simply shut off, as sometimes it does that when in sleep mode for a duration. (Which I have been unable to fix through the Light Locker settings.) I have to force a restart, lose the download again, and start over.

Using a flash drive in a library computer hardly works either, as the download time surpasses the allotted time allowed on the computers.

I tried utilizing the available torrent, but it says the tracker failed, for whatever reason.

I've also tried downloading the file on my smartphone so I could upload it to Google Drive, but the download fails there too.

At this point, what can I do to get my hands on a copy of this desktop image?

What I need:

- Stability, so that I'm not constantly losing the download progress and starting over
- Something faster than the regular websites, as the time to download is causing most of the problems.

Comment: Your problem is not Ubuntu related but greedy cheap Library not giving free wifi forever. I suggest to try another library that is not so greedy with the wifi or a friend that can give you a hand. Good luck friend.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the connections available to you are too slow and/or restricted to be able to download this. I can suggest trying a different mirror to see if it's faster for you: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors. Optionally, contact a local Ubuntu user group in your region and see if they could help download on your behalf and prepare installation media for you.

Comment: Alright. 

Sorry if it did seem like I'm off-topic. I'd thought it'd be relevant since someone might point me to a mirror site, or else tell me about a download manager within Ubuntu that would at least allow me to restart broken downloads from where they left off.

It's an annoying problem, but I'll solve it.

I tried DLing at work, but according to their connection speed, it'd take 175 hours. Man. 

Right now I'm trying to DL a light version of Puppy Linux to see if I could at least get a more stable platform to DL the Lubuntu from, otherwise I'll recruit a friend to put it on my flash drive